# How does this NAWK script work to show the ports being used by a process on Solaris?

Tags: process, solaris, ports, nawk

I am trying to understand how the following command works (from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/awk-nawk-gawk/)):

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
pfiles /proc/* 2>&- | 
  nawk 'END {
  if (f) print p 
    }
/^[0-9]/ { 
    if (f) print p, RS 
    p = $0
    f = 0
  }
/INET / {
  sub(/.*INET/,"") 
  p = p ? p RS $0 : $0
  f = 1 
  }'
```

This command works well (in SOLARIS 5.10)  and shows all the ports opened by processes.

I understand that, `pfiles /proc/*` displays a bunch of output related to all processes by querying the /proc/ filesystem. From the man-page:

```
 pfiles              Report fstat(2) and fcntl(2) information
                     for  all  open files in each process. In
                     addition, a path to the file is reported
                     if  the  information  is  available from
                     /proc/pid/path. This is not  necessarily
                     the same name used to open the file. See
                     proc(4) for more information.
```

The output from pfiles is then processed by **nawk** ('New Awk').

#### Questions

1. Could you please explain how NAWK is processing the output of pfiles in the following command? It would be most helpful to know how the parameters `f`, `p` and `$0` mean.
2. In the first line, what does redirection of standard error to `&-` mean? Does it mean the standard error stream is being [closed](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/182759-exec-2-what-does-mean.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to read that script once or twice to make sure I got it straight in 
my head. It's a little confusing because we see the END at the beginning.

`$0` is the entire line.

The line `/^[0-9]/` matches the process id (specifically) and that block
then sets the sentinel variable f to 0.

The block starting with `/INET /` matches (and then strips, via the sub(..))
the open port number. The sentinel value f is set to 1 so that we know to
print differently when we hit the `END`. Each time we finish an output
collection (ie, the entire output from pfiles for a process), we hit the `END`
block and print the output.

BTW, the `RS` is the Record Separator.

Running the script on just one process might make it a little easier to get
the head around it.

Sorry, forgot to answer your other question re the redirection.

```
2>&-
```

in this context means "redirect stderr from the process to standard input",
so that `nawk` takes input from there rather than a file.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer with the note about redirection. However, from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), it would seem that `&-` is used to close a stream which would otherwise be inherited by child processes. Accordingly, `2>&-` would mean, close the `sterr` stream so that it is not passed on to nawk.